# Adding icon to url file for multiple users

Tags: windows, icons, links

I have procedure running on multiple PCs which automatically synchronizes local files with server. During this process a .lnk pointing to local .url file is created.

Is it possible to somehow "hard wire" specific location of ".ico" icon for ".url" file on server, so when the sync procedure runs, the newly created .lnk will share icon with that .url file?

Both files (ico, url) are in the same local/server folder with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with .url files, because .url files only contain the url, no other information. It therefor gets the icon by the browser. The .lnk file does have properties of an icon and they can be changed.

Comment: Yes, that is right. Unfortunately thats not possible to do, since it would require each user to manualy set the icon. But thanks for the reply anyway :)

Comment: What if you create the .lnk file, and simply copy it?

Comment: Yes that would work, but the lnk file is created during sync procedure. I would edit this procedure but its part of third party software. I can only specify attributes of created lnk file (but its of no use here)

Comment: I don't know enough of your script, but it might be possible to alter the link file afterwards to change the icon.